# Python2 convert function output list to callable array

Tags: python, list, plot, callable

I have a program I've been working on all weekend and it contains the correct output, however it outputs a list that is not callable, and I need to be able to build a plot from it. How do I modify the list to make it callable?

## Homework #3 - Convolution

```
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)

#04-01 Convolution


def conv395(x,h):
        #Function to convolve x input signal and h impulse response
   
    M = len(h)-1
    L = len(x)
    Ly = M+L
    LOL = []

    def ConV(x,h,n):
        y = (h[m]*x[(n-1)-m])
        return (y)

    for n in range(0,Ly+1):
    
        mx = n-L+1
        
        if mx < 1:
            n = n+1
            #print("SPACE")
            Y1 = 0
            
            if n <= M+1:
                
                L1 = []
                for m in range(n):
                    #print(n) 
                    
                    y = ConV(x,h,n)
                    Y1 = y + Y1
                    
                L1.append(Y1)
                LOL.append(str(L1))
                #print Y,     
    
    ###LOL = np.int32(LOL)
 
                  
            if n > M+1:
                #print("Space")
                L2 = []
                N = n-1
                n = M+1
                Y2 = 0
                
                for m in range(n):                                     
                    y2 = h[m]*x[(N-m)] 
                    Y2 = Y2 + y2
                L2.append(Y2)
                LOL.append(str(L2))
                    
    
      
        if mx > 1:
               #print("space")  
               L3 = []   
               if n > M+1:
                   Y3 = 0
               
               for m in range(n-L,M+1):
                   y3 = h[m]*x[m-(n-L)]
                   Y3 = Y3 + y3
               L3.append(Y3)
               LOL.append(str(L3))
    
    
    return(LOL)             


h = [1,2,-1,1]
x = [1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1] 

Y = conv395(x,h)
print(callable(Y))
```

The OUTPUT shows that the list is not callable, and I the output looks like this ['[1]', '[3]', '[3]', '[5]', '[3]', '[7]', '[4]', '[3]', '[3]', '[0]', '[1]']
I've tried every form of conversion I could find on the internet and it won't budge. Suggestions?

Comment: `list` objects are not callable. What tells you that it has to be?

Comment: Why would you like `LOL` to be a callable ? It is a list. I am not sure to get your point.

Comment: Lists are not callable. It's not clear why you want to make it callable. To access an element from the list, you use something like `L[0]`, not `L(0)`.

Comment: My bad all, I thought that it needed to be callable in order to graph it...but appears I was using plt.plot(Y) wrong, and it was giving me the object is not callable error. Looks to be working fine now though. Thanks!